# I have Windows 10 and it takes up to 20 minutes to start. Please help me, I'm going crazy

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

It's already been a few months since my computer really takes a long time to start up and lately the situation has become unmanageable, especially if I need a pc to do things quickly. 5 months ago I formatted the pc for the same problem, but after a few months, here I am again. So I installed the tool to analyze the performance of my pc but I can't figure out where the problem is... I am attaching the .etl file, can someone be so kind and help me? Thank you so much <3

Etl file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ocxTcMBSy5CIygxFzAcnKsx145Jlz4ir/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's a very large file. Instead of looking at that, which would be too much work for me right now, I'd rather go for the obvious potential reasons: How much RAM do you have (4 GB is likely not enough)? Is Windows booting from a harddisk (bad idea) as opposed to an SSD (good idea)? If you have a harddisk, how much free space is there (should be at least 20-30 GB)? Also, do you shut down your computer when you don't use it (not such a good idea if you want it to be quickly available), or do you put it into standby or hibernation (better idea)?

Comment: You should provide more details about your specs. In general, HDDs and Windows 10's tens of dozens of files don't do fine together.

Comment: I saw that files inside the temp folder were taking a really long time, so I deleted them. Boot now is faster. Let's hope everything goes well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> -> `Startups` -> `Disable unused services and applications autostarts.`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> -> `Services` -> `Open Services` -> `sort by Status or Startup Type` -> `Disable unused.`

Install Sysinternals Autoruns: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns
Download link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Disable unused services and applications autostarts.

`Windows Menu` -> `Task Scheduler` -> `Disable Telemetry and unused service/apps, etc.`

Comment: Thank you, resolved by upgrading to an SSD